# Problem with barcode extension - XSLT XSLFO

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, barcode4j

While trying to create barcode with:  barcode4j-fop-ext-complete.jar, locally on my computer with command  `..\fop-2.5-bin\fop-2.5\fop\fop.bat -c config1.xml -xml 6314587.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl  output.pdf`, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class 
org.krysalis.barcode4j.fop0205.BarcodeElementMapping can not implement 
org.apache.fop.fo.ElementMapping, 
because it is not an interface (org.apache.fop.fo.ElementMapping is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Did anyone encounter this problem? How can I fix it?

Is the stylesheet I have barcode implementation as below:

```
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block>
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                        <barcode:barcode xmlns:barcode="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns" message="123" orientation="90">
                                            <barcode:code128>
                                                <barcode:height>8mm</barcode:height>
                                            </barcode:code128>
                                        </barcode:barcode>
                                    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
```

Comment: barcode4j looks old and unmaintained: http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/download.html. So perhaps it's not surprising that it doesn't work with the latest FOP.

Comment: The `fop0205` package name seems to reference a very _very_ **very** old FOP version (0.20.5). Maybe there is a more recent barcode4j jar?

Comment: The original barcode4j on sourceforge is dead but I maintain a fork with continued development and artifacts published to maven central. See: 
https://github.com/singingbush/barcode4j

Answer (score 0):

Use a maintained barcode4j fork: https://github.com/SingingBush/barcode4j
(the barcode4j-cli jar is built when you clone and do a mvn build)

And then do something like:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object>
  <barcode:barcode message="123456789" orientation="90">
    <barcode:code128>
      <barcode:height>15mm</barcode:height>
      <barcode:module-width>0.21mm</barcode:module-width>
      <barcode:codesets>ABC</barcode:codesets>
      <barcode:quiet-zone enabled="true">10mw</barcode:quiet-zone>
    </barcode:code128>
  </barcode:barcode>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```